# How to clone a list without sharing the reference?

Tags: apex, list

I need a best way to avoid the object reference between two list. For example, I have list of `Contact` records and I create one more list in which I make the changes to each record's `LastName`. My problem is, if I make changes in new list, the first list last name also changes. Here is my code.

```
list<contact> cont = new List<contact>([select id, lastName from contact where lastname Like '%xyz%' Limit 3]);
list<Contact> editedCont = new List<Contact>();
editedCont.addAll(cont);
for(contact c: editedCont)
   c.lastname = 'abc';
System.debug(cont);
System.debug(editedcont);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop at all, this is exactly what `List.deepClone()` is for.

From the [`List` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

> **deepClone(preserveId, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)**
>
> Makes a duplicate copy of a list of sObject records, including the sObject records themselves.

This is in contrast to the regular `clone()` method, whose documentation says

> **clone()**
>
> Makes a duplicate copy of a list.
>
> Note that if this is a list of sObject records, the duplicate list will only be a shallow copy of the list. *That is, the duplicate will have references to each object, but the sObject records themselves will not be duplicated*.
>
> To also copy the sObject records, you must use the deepClone method.

Since you do want to make copies of the sObject records themselves, `deepClone()` is what you'd want to use.

Comment: I mean...you do still need to loop through if you want to set all the `LastName` fields to a specific value.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Right, forgot about that bit. Though now that you say that, I wonder if it is possible to avoid all loops if you were to shove the cloned list into a `StandardSetController` (SSC), set a field on the prototype object of the SSC, and then use `StandardSetController.save()`. Of course, assuming that would work, you'd only be able to set the target field(s) of all the records to a common value.

Comment: Wouldn't be too much work to test out! :)

Comment: deepClone works for sObject list only, any suggestions for a custom List<T> of any type?

Comment: @VarunC Not at the moment. This sounds worthy of being its own question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will get you going.. not sure exactly what you're trying to do

```
List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();

for(Contact c: [select id, lastName from contact where lastname Like '%xyz%' Limit 3])
{
    c.lastname = 'abc';
    contactsToUpdate.add(c);

}

update contactsToUpdate;
```